# Block Inappropriate Content from Chatroom

Tags: objective-c, chatroom, cfstring

Basically, I have a chat room in an iphone app and I want to block inappropriate words from it. I have an array of these words called blackList. However, whenever I run the code below, I get the error that "`use of undeclared identifier 'foundRange'`" and the warning that "`incompatible pointer types passing NSString to parameter of type 'CFStringRef (aka 'const struct _ CFString`". What is the problem? Please provide code in your answer.Here is my code:

```
- (void)displayChatMessage:(NSString*)message fromUser:(NSString*)userName {

    int i=0;

    for (i=0; i<[blackList count] ; i++){

        NSString *one = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[blackList objectAtIndex:i]];

        if (CFStringFindWithOptions(message,one , CFRangeMake(0,CFStringGetLength(message)), kCFCompareCaseInsensitive, &foundRange) == true) {
           /*do nothing*/
        }

        else {

            [chat appendTextAfterLinebreak:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", userName, message]];
        [chat scrollToBottom:chat];

        }


    }





}
```

Comment: First of all, from where is `foundRange`? Where is it declared? Then, you're using `CFStringRef` fonction with an object `NSString`. So what do you expect if you don't put the right parameters. Of course, there is bridge between `CFStringRef` & `NSString`, but you could look a little.

Comment: Also, note that this is a bad way to do what you're trying to do. For example, if the word "ass" is in your list, you'll block legitimate words like "classic" and users won't understand why.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Answer (score 0):

NSString and CFString support Toll-free bridging, which means they can be used interchangeably. But when Automatic Reference Counting came along a few years ago, things were tweaked a little bit. ARC doesn't manage Core Foundation objects because they are C, and not Objective-C. So you have to determine what you want the ownership semantics to be. You can probably get away with casting as __bridge.

For more, read up on this - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010677